# Why does this `npm version` command break?

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

Quite simply, this command works:

```
npm version 0.13.0-20190723T144221.855f01d
```

But this one doesn't:

```
npm version 0.13.0-20190723T125957.0665893
```

Why? It broke our build process, so it would be useful to understand why this occurred.

Comment: "Doesn't work" in what way? Error messages? Output other than expected? Formatted your hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the parts behind the hyphen are allowed to be numbers that have a leading **`0`** (unless the number equals 0).

This only applies to *numbers*, making both `.855f01d` and `.0855f01d` valid, but `.0855` is not valid.

This can be found in Rule 9 of https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html:

> A pre-release version MAY be denoted by appending a **hyphen** and a series of **dot separated identifiers** immediately following the patch version.
>
> Identifiers MUST comprise only ASCII alphanumerics and hyphen [0-9A-Za-z-]. Identifiers MUST NOT be empty.
>
> **Numeric identifiers MUST NOT include leading zeroes.**

For testing purposes, you can fill in your proposed or attempted **Version** on this page: https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/ .